# Error in Adding metadata into Seurat Object

Tags: r, error-handling, seurat

Right now I have a dataframe called **"train_mean"** which has gene expression symbols(colnames) and values  of each SubjectID (rownames),  and also other df called **"meta_df"** which contains clinical data related to each SubjectID.

In order to perform my further analysis UMAP on the "train_mean" df, I need to first create and SeuratObject and match them up by their Subject.ID. However I always get the below error output:

`Error: Cannot add more or fewer cell meta.data information without values being named with cell names`

I have checked the `colnames(seurat_obj)` and the `rownames(meta_df)` , they contains the same amount of Subject ID. But I still got this error. Do you guys know why?

Below are the codes:

```
#before we do UMAP, we need to first match the two df (merged_df and train_mean) by Subject ID

meta_df1 <- log_merged_df[,-c(1:8)]

#remove the duplicated row base on subject.ID

meta_df <- meta_df1[!duplicated(meta_df1$Subject.ID),]
row.names(meta_df) <- meta_df$Subject.ID
meta_df <- meta_df[,-1]

#this contains only the clinical data of all samples

#we also load the imputed train / validation dataset into the environment, making its SubjectID as the rownames

row.names(train_mean) <- train_mean$Subject.ID

#deleting the redundant SubjectID column

train_mean <- train_mean[,-1]

#we need to transpose the train_mean1 df before creating Seurat Object

t_train_mean <- t(train_mean)
seurat_obj <- CreateSeuratObject(counts = t_train_mean)
colnames(seurat_obj)
rownames(seurat_obj)

#now the column names for the seurat_obj is Subject ID and rowname is gene symbol

#match the meta_df with seurat_obj by Subject.ID

matched_meta <- meta_df[match(colnames(seurat_obj),rownames(meta_df)),]
rownames(matched_meta) <- colnames(seurat_obj)
seurat_obj[["clinical_meta"]] <- matched_meta
```

Then I got this error.

thanks for helping

Comment: Rather than describing what was done and showing an error message, show exactly what was done (i.e., code).

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the following using my own data
Here is the code:

```
###1. read raw counts/expression matrix ------
pancreas.sub <- Read10X_h5("expression.h5")
str(pancreas.sub)
metadata <- read.table("metadatatable.tsv", header = T, sep = "\t")
head(metadata)

meta <- data.frame(metadata)
head(meta)  
  
### create Seurat Object with count data

pancreas <- CreateSeuratObject(counts = pancreas.sub, project = "TISCH2", min.cells = 3, min.features = 200)
str(pancreas)
pancreas@meta.data

#Add metadata dataframe to seurat object

row.names(meta) <- colnames(x=pancreas)
colnames(x= pancreas)
pancreas_meta <- AddMetaData(pancreas, meta, row.names("Celltype"))
head(pancreas_meta)
```

The output is:

```
                    orig.ident nCount_RNA nFeature_RNA                Cell           Celltype Patient Source Gender   Stage TNMstage
T2_AAAGATGAGCTTCGCG         T2   1511.538          859 T2_AAAGATGAGCTTCGCG        Acinar cell      T2  Tumor   Male Primary      IIB
T2_AAATGCCCAAGCCGCT         T2   2708.970         3480 T2_AAATGCCCAAGCCGCT        Acinar cell      T2  Tumor   Male Primary      IIB
T2_AAGGCAGCAGGGAGAG         T2   2531.895         6373 T2_AAGGCAGCAGGGAGAG        Acinar cell      T2  Tumor   Male Primary      IIB
T2_ACACTGAAGACCACGA         T2   2528.939         1908 T2_ACACTGAAGACCACGA        Acinar cell      T2  Tumor   Male Primary      IIB
T2_ACACTGATCCTTTCTC         T2   2325.701         3511 T2_ACACTGATCCTTTCTC        Acinar cell      T2  Tumor   Male Primary      IIB
T2_ACAGCTATCAAGCCTA         T2   1974.966         1507 T2_ACAGCTATCAAGCCTA        Acinar cell      T2  Tumor   Male Primary      IIB
T2_ACCCACTCATAAGACA         T2   2028.527         1518 T2_ACCCACTCATAAGACA        Acinar cell      T2  Tumor   Male Primary      IIB
T2_ACGATACAGAGCTGGT         T2   2026.956         2393 T2_ACGATACAGAGCTGGT        Acinar cell      T2  Tumor   Male Primary      IIB
T2_ACTGATGTCTTGAGAC         T2   2800.728         2678 T2_ACTGATGTCTTGAGAC Ductal cell type 1      T2  Tumor   Male Primary      IIB
T2_AGCGTCGAGTGAACGC         T2   1933.352         1073 T2_AGCGTCGAGTGAACGC Ductal cell type 1      T2  Tumor   Male Primary      IIB
```